# Insert a character at multiple positions in a string at once

Tags: regex, r, text, gsub

Let us say I have a string

```
"ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd"
```

What I want to do is insert a space character at multiple positions at once.

For eg. I want to insert space character at randomly chosen two positions say 4 and 8.

So the output should be

```
"ABCD EFGH I56dfsdfd"
```

What is the most effective way of doing this? Given the string can have any type of characters in it (not just the alphabets).

Comment: Not knowing the particulars of R, I can only comment generically; but this does not seem like a regex problem.  It seems more like a problem to address by generating two random indexes and inserting a space at each generated index.

Comment: @RichardScriven umm....after position 4 (i.e after 'D') and after position 8 (i.e. after 'H'). I made an edit to correct the desired output.

Comment: @J0e3gan yes, that can done (i.e hard coding the whole logic). But I am sure in R there must be some shorter and nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution based on regular expressions:

```
vec <- "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd"

# sample two random positions
pos <- sample(nchar(vec), 2)
# [1] 6 4

# generate regex pattern
pat <- paste0("(?=.{", nchar(vec) - pos, "}$)", collapse = "|")
# [1] "(?=.{11}$)|(?=.{13}$)"

# insert spaces at (after) positions
gsub(pat, " ", vec, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "ABCD EF GHI56dfsdfd"
```

This approach is based on positive lookaheads, e.g., `(?=.{11}$)`. In this example, a space is inserted at 11 characters before the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

A bit more brute-force-y than Sven's:

```
randomSpaces <- function(txt) {
  pos <- sort(sample(nchar(txt), 2))
  paste(substr(txt, 1, pos[1]), " ", 
        substr(txt, pos[1]+1, pos[2]), " ", 
        substr(txt, pos[2]+1, nchar(txt)), collapse="", sep="")  
}

for (i in 1:10) print(randomSpaces("ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd"))

## [1] "ABCDEFG HI56 dfsdfd"
## [1] "ABC DEFGHI5 6dfsdfd"
## [1] "AB CDEFGHI56dfsd fd"
## [1] "ABCDEFGHI 5 6dfsdfd"
## [1] "ABCDEF GHI56dfsdf d"
## [1] "ABC DEFGHI56dfsdf d"
## [1] "ABCD EFGHI56dfsd fd"
## [1] "ABCDEFGHI56d fsdfd "
## [1] "AB CDEFGH I56dfsdfd"
## [1] "A BCDE FGHI56dfsdfd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, here's a function that simplifies this approach:

```
##insert pattern in string at position
substrins <- function(ins, x, ..., pos=NULL, offset=0){
    stopifnot(is.numeric(pos), 
              is.numeric(offset), 
              !is.null(pos))
    offset <- offset[1]
    pat <- paste0("(?=.{", nchar(x) - pos - (offset-1), "}$)", collapse = "|")
    gsub(pattern = pat, replacement = ins, x = x, ..., perl = TRUE)
}

# insert space at position 10
substrins(" ", "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd", pos = 10)
##[1] "ABCDEFGHI 56dfsdfd"

# insert pattern before position 10 (i.e. at position 9)
substrins(" ", "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd", pos = 10, offset=-1)
##[1] "ABCDEFGH I56dfsdfd"

# insert pattern after position 10 (i.e. at position 11)
substrins(" ", "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd", pos = 10, offset=1)
##[1] "ABCDEFGHI5 6dfsdfd"
```

Now to do what the OP wanted:

```
# insert space at position 4 and 8
substrins(" ", "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd", pos = c(4,8))
##[1] "ABC DEFG HI56dfsdfd"

# insert space after position 4 and 8 (as per OP's desired output)
substrins(" ", "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd", pos = c(4,8), offset=1)
##[1] "ABCD EFGH I56dfsdfd"
```

To replicate the other, more brute-force-y answer one would do:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- "ABCDEFGHI56dfsdfd"
for (i in 1:10) print(substrins(" ", x, pos = sample(nchar(x), 2)))
##[1] "ABCD EFGHI56d fsdfd"
##[1] "ABCDEF GHI56dfs dfd"
##[1] " ABCDEFGHI56dfsd fd"
##[1] "ABCDEFGH I56dfs dfd"
##[1] "ABCDEFG HI 56dfsdfd"
##[1] "ABCDEFG HI56dfsdf d"
##[1] "ABCDEFGHI 56 dfsdfd"
##[1] "A BCDEFGHI56dfs dfd"
##[1] " ABCD EFGHI56dfsdfd"
##[1] "ABCDE FGHI56dfsd fd"
```